# Añadir a la salida los siguientes datos?

Tags: java

Como podría introducir a la salida de este código el id del producto exacto, su descripción exacta y su precio, es decir, el Portatil Asus tiene un id 1, con una cantidad aleatoria, la descripción de ese portátil y el precio de ese portátil sin tener en cuenta la suma total de la cantidad de portátiles

```
public class ProductGenerator {

public static String [] generarProductosAleatorios(int total) {
    String [] productosAleatorios = new String[total];

    String [] nombre = {"Portatil Asus", "Teclado mecánico", "Monitor 22 HD" , "Raton inalámbrico" , "Sobremesa EpicPc", "Altavoz bluethoot"};

    String [] cantidad = {"1" , "2" , "3", "4" };


    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {

        productosAleatorios[i]= "Id: " + ", " + "Producto: " + nombre[(int)(Math.floor(Math.random()*((nombre.length-1)-0+1)+0))] + ", " + "Cantidad: " +
                cantidad[(int)(Math.floor(Math.random()*((cantidad.length-1)-0+1)+0))] + ", " + "Descripción: " + ", " + " Precio: " ;
        }

    return productosAleatorios;

}
public static void imprimir(String [] productosGenerados) {
    for (int i = 0; i < productosGenerados.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(productosGenerados[i]);
    }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    imprimir(generarProductosAleatorios(20));
    }
```

}

La salida es esta:

```
Id: , Producto: Teclado mecánico, Cantidad: 4, Descripción: ,  Precio: 
Id: , Producto: Teclado mecánico, Cantidad: 1, Descripción: ,  Precio: 
Id: , Producto: Portatil Asus, Cantidad: 4, Descripción: ,  Precio: 
Id: , Producto: Raton inalámbrico, Cantidad: 1, Descripción: ,  Precio:
```

Y quisiera que se muestre esto:

```
Id: 1, Producto: Teclado mecanico, Cantidad: 4, Descripcion: Este es un teclado mecánico con leds ,  Precio: 24,95 €
Id: 1, Producto: Teclado mecanico, Cantidad: 1, Descripcion: Este es un teclado mecánico con leds ,  Precio: 24,95 €
Id: 2, Producto: Portatil Asus, Cantidad: 4, Descripcion: Esto es un portatil de ultima generacion  ,  Precio: 654,85 €
Id: 3, Producto: Raton inalambrico, Cantidad: 1, Descripcion: Raton inalambrico marga Logitech ,  Precio: 14,99 €
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No se entiende bien cual es tu problema...

Comment: He intentado corregir la pregunta, es mi primera vez preguntando en stackoverflow y no controlo muy bien. A ver si con las modificaciones puedes entender cual es mi duda

Answer (score 1):

En realidad no estas agregando los valores para descripción y al precio:

```
+ "Descripción: " + ", " + " Precio: " ;
```

debes agregarlos, pero para esto debes agregar dos arrays para obtener la información relacionada a descripción y al precio:

```
String [] descripcion = {"Este es un teclado mecánico con leds" , "Esto es un portatil de ultima generacion" , "Raton inalambrico marga Logitech", "Raton inalambrico marga Microsoft"};

String [] precio = {"24,95 €" , "654,85 €" , "14,99 €", "12,99 €"};
```

y concatenarlos :

```
    productosAleatorios[i]= "Id: " + ", " + "Producto: " + nombre[(int)(Math.floor(Math.random()*((nombre.length-1)-0+1)+0))] + ", " + "Cantidad: " +
            cantidad[(int)(Math.floor(Math.random()*((cantidad.length-1)-0+1)+0))] + ", " 
            + "Descripción: " + descripcion[(int)(Math.floor(Math.random()*((cantidad.length-1)-0+1)+0))]
           + ", " + " Precio: " + precio[(int)(Math.floor(Math.random()*((cantidad.length-1)-0+1)+0))];
```

Para tener una salida como la deseada.

Answer (score -2):

1)productosAleatorios[i]= "Id: " + 1+ i+"....
2)podrias hacer otro array con Los precios y llamarlos multiplicandolo por la cantidas y agregarlo despues de "precio:"
3)hacer otro array con Las descripciones o agregarlo Las descripciones a Los nombres aun que quede medio feo

Comment: lee [answer] y mejora tu publicación; le hace falta mucho contenido para empezar que hace ese código? y por que piensas que es una respuesta?